# micro python - Raspberry PI pico board - eeprom 24c32 page by page programming

Tags: python

I am using a 24c32 eeprom to store my alarm data for my time switch product.

Summer alarm   palm_summer = bytearray(480)  - 15 pages of 32 bytes each.
pbuffer3    = bytearray(32)   - 1 page temp buffer

I would like to transfer 0-31 bytes, then 32-63 bytes, and so on - for 15 pages to pbuffer3 and xfer it to the 24c32 eeprom using the micro python function :

```
i2c.writeto_mem(0x57, 0, pbuffer3, addrsize=18)         # this is for page 0

i2c.writeto_mem(0x57, 32, pbuffer3, addrsize=18)         # this is for page 1
```

for transferring 32 bytes from palm_summer to pbuffer3,for page0,  i am doing the following :

```
 for i in range(0,32,1)
     pbuffer3[i] = palm_summer[i]    # this gives me assignment error.
```

I made a small change to avoid the above error

```
x = list(palm_summer)
for i in range(0,32,1)
    pbuffer3[i] = x[i]   # this gives me a different error
```

kindly suggest suitable code or identify errors in the above

Comment: "Assignment error" doesn't tell us anything about what went wrong.  "A different error" tells us even less.  *POST THE ACTUAL ERROR MESSAGES!*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "kindly suggest suitable code or identify errors in the above" is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

One potential error I can identify is `addrsize=18`. According to the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc0336.pdf), it should be 2 x 8 bit = 16.

For a suitable code to transfer the full content of palm_summer I would suggest:

```py
palm_summer = bytearray(480)
bytes_per_page = 32
# create iterator address i = 0, 32, 64, ...)
for i in range(0, len(palm_summer), bytes_per_page):
    # extract chunk of 32 bytes from palm_summer
    page_bytes = palm_summer[i : i + bytes_per_page]
    # convert bytearray to bytes and transmit it to device at mem-address i
    i2c.writeto_mem(0x57, i, bytes(page_bytes), addrsize=16)
```

This way, there is no need for a temporary buffer, just take the 32 bytes from palm_summer directly.